# Problem with membership import

Tags: civimember, import

I completed a membership import. Online screen messages indicate that the import was successful, but none of the members appear on reports and contacts do not have membership relationship.  What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem.

When I did the initial import, I used a dummy start date value of 01/01/1961 for members that had a null value for start date. I believe this date caused the problem.  I changed the date to 01/01/1995 and the import worked, plus I can see the data.